# Find Informix Db Locale

Tags: c#, odbc, informix

I am having below piece of code where i try to connect to IBM's Informix database.

```cs
public void MakeConnection()
{
    string ConnectionString =
        @"Database=databasename;
          Host=ipaddress;
          Server=servername;
          Service=port;
          Protocol = olsoctcp; 
          UID = userid; 
          Password = password;";
    IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (IfxException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Getting below error on opening a connection.

> ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Database locale information mismatch.

When i try connecting using `windows ODBC Data sources` application, by creating a new user data source under User DSN and providing all necessary values under each section of `Informix ODBC driver setup`, i am able to connect successfully.

All i understand is that the client application's and database's `Database Locale` value should be same for proper query execution, and i have tried using `en_US.57372 and en_US.UTF8` DB Locale while configuring in user DSN's which worked pretty well. I am posting here a image for better understanding.

[image: ODBC Driver Setup for Informix and connectivity test]

Appreciate if anyone can help me in knowing where i can find DB Locale configured for in an Informix database and also in detail on what actually causes for this error.

Comment: If you can use connect to and query the database, you can find the locale with the following query: `SELECT * FROM systables WHERE tabid IN ( 90, 91 );`. After that you can add the locale information to your connection string ( check the online Informix .net documentation ).

Comment: @LuísMarques thanks for help;

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to connect to database from test application!. Okay here we go,

***Step 1:*** First we need to find what Database locale that database allows us to use? so following *@Luis Marques* way as he mentioned in comment section, found that `Database Locale` used is `en_US.57372`, also `en_US.UTF8` is supported.

***Step 2:*** By default, connection object's `client locale and database locale` property values will be  whatever default value was set when `Informix ODBC driver` was installed.

Slightly modified my test app code as below,

```
   public void MakeConnection()
        {
            string ConnectionString = "Database=databasename;Host=ipaddress;Server=servername;Service=port;Protocol = olsoctcp; UID = userid; Password = password;";
            IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            conn.ClientLocale = "en_US.UTF8";
            conn.DatabaseLocale = "en_US.UTF8";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (IfxException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }    
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

So manually assigning `client and database locale` values for connection object with what we have got in *step 1* solved the issue.